# Pandas How to Pivot columns that come in sets of 3 into rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transformation

I have a pandas df that I need to transform and pivot. Each season has 3 columns associated with it (start, end and rate). I am looking to pivot these columns and at the end have only 3 columns start, end and rate
[image]

df:

```
ID S1start  S1end  Rate  S2start  S2end   Rate  S3start  S3end  Rate  S4start  S4end  Rate
1  1/1/21  1/31/21  80   2/1/21  2/28/21   85   3/1/21  3/31/21  90   4/1/21  4/30/21  95
```

final:

```
 ID  Start     End   Rate
  1  1/1/21  1/31/21  80
  1  2/1/21  2/28/21  85
  1  3/1/21  3/31/21  90
  1  4/1/21  4/30/21  95
```

Comment: Do you always want every three columns or can they be in a random order?

Comment: nope, the order needs to be preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.filter` with `pd.concat`:

```
In [589]: start = df.stack().filter(like='start').reset_index()[0]    
In [590]: end = df.stack().filter(like='end').reset_index()[0]
In [591]: rate = df.stack().filter(like='Rate').reset_index()[0]

In [594]: x = pd.concat([start.rename('Start'), end.rename('End'), rate.rename('Rate')], 1)
```

Let's say you have `2` static cols: `ID, PropCode`. You can attach these cols to `x` like this:

```
In [640]: x[['ID', 'PropCode']] = df[['ID', 'PropCode']].values.tolist() * len(x)

In [641]: x
Out[641]: 
    Start      End Rate  ID  PropCode
0  1/1/21  1/31/21   80   1     52032
1  2/1/21  2/28/21   85   1     52032
2  3/1/21  3/31/21   90   1     52032
3  4/1/21  4/30/21   95   1     52032
```

Comment: There are some static columns like ID that I want retained as well. is that possible?

Comment: Can you share a sample with the static cols and also post the expected output in that case.

Comment: I have posted the screen shot. Those first 7 columns are static & will basically need to be copied over to each row. PropCode is the primary key.

Comment: @SuhasN I've edited my answer. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `reshape` , if the format prefixed

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.values.reshape((-1,3)), columns=['start','end','rate'])
Out[419]: 
    start      end rate
0  1/1/21  1/31/21   80
1  2/1/21  2/28/21   85
2  3/1/21  3/31/21   90
3  4/1/21  4/30/21   95
```

Comment: There are columns before S1start in the original df and the number of seasons is not static

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html); at the moment you have to install the latest development version from [github](https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor):

The data you shared has patterns (some columns ends with `start`, others with `end`, and some start with `Rate`), we can use these patterns to reshape the data;

```
# install latest dev version
# pip install git+https://github.com/ericmjl/pyjanitor.git
 import janitor
df.pivot_longer(
    index="ID",
    names_pattern=("start$", "end$", "^Rate"),
    names_to=("Start", "End", "Rate"),
)

   ID   Start    End    Rate
0   1   1/1/21  1/31/21 80
1   1   2/1/21  2/28/21 85
2   1   3/1/21  3/31/21 90
3   1   4/1/21  4/30/21 95
```

`names_to` takes the new names, while `names_pattern` takes the patterns, and reshapes the data accordingly.